# Python sorting arrays to get two digit values

Tags: python

I have an array A = [1 - 100] and I need to find the sum of all the two digit values in this array. How would I approach this? I have tried :

```
def solution(A):
    A =array[0-100])
    while  A > 9 & A < 99
        total = sum(A)
        print "%s" % total
```

)

Is there a  function that given an array consisting of N integers returns the sum of all two digit numbers i.e A = [1,1000,80, -91] the function should return -11(as the two are 80 and -91). not a range, multiple array

Comment: You should test your code in an interpreter, because there's some syntax errors.

Comment: There are many syntax problems with your code. You should review how to declare arrays, access array elements, and loop over arrays in python.

Comment: @Cecilia i need help to get  a function that given an array consisting of N integers returns the sum of all two digit numbers i.e A = [1,1000,80, -91] the function should return -11(as the two are 80 and -91). not a range, multiple arrays

Comment: Then you should use the "edit" link to change your question. That wasn't clear in the original question. You should also try running your own code and fix any syntax errors.

Comment: pleasee i need this

Comment: Mr Okiri, it is not difficult to edit your question. You can copy and paste the comment you left for me. However, you also need to keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You should show your own efforts instead of pestering others for the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyword `and` rather than the bitwise `&`.

Edit: a fuller answer, as that's not the only thing wrong:

```
def solution():
    A = range(101)
    total = sum([a for a in A if 9 < a <= 99])
    print total
```

This uses list comprehension and chained inequalities, so is pretty 'pythonic'.

Comment: Although @Pit beat me to writing an identical answer in the comments.

Comment: No worries -- I removed the comment since there are more issues than that.

Comment: @spco forgive what i am about to do man, please, i have a dilemma here i do not even know how to start on this.is there a way that given a positive iunteger N, prints the consecutive numbers from 1 to N, each on a separate line. However, any number divisible by 3,5,or 7 should be replaced by the word Fizz, Buzz or Woof respectively..if its divisible by both 3 and 5 it outputs FizzBuzz and if all it outputs FizzBuzzWoof –

Answer (score 0):

There is tons of errors in your code, please next time before posting,spend some time try to figure it out yourself and be sure that your code at lest doesn't contain any obvious syntax error.

By array, I assume you're talking about a `list`. And change it to range(101) for every number from 0 to 100

```
def solution(A): 
    return sum([x for x in range(A) if len(str(abs(x))) == 2])
print(solution(101))
```

As a side note, use `and` instead of `&` since that's a bitwise-or sign.

Comment: What does the call to `list()` do for you in this example?

Comment: Where does the `.digits()` method get imported from?

Comment: I always thought it has one oh well

Comment: Was the irony lost on you that you chided the OP for not syntax checking his question and then submitted an example answer with an `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'digits'` error?

Comment: When the irony is on you because it's not a syntax error. And how am I supposed to check in my phone

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension and check if the length of the string-format is equal to 2, like so:

```
    sum([x if len(str(x))==2 else 0 for x in xrange(1,101)])
```

Comment: Why not avoid the `else`, and temporary list, by doing `sum(x for x in xrange(1, 101) if len(str(x)) == 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways to go about the problem, the first is most similar to the approach you appear to be trying:

```
def solution1(array):
    total = 0

    for a in array:
        if 9 < a < 100:
            total += a
    return total

print(solution1(range(101)))
```

And here's a more compact solution using a comprehension (actually, a generator expression):

```
def solution2(array):
    return sum(a for a in array if 9 < a < 100)

print(solution2(range(101)))
```

Note that in your original you're confusing loops and conditionals.